# $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1+x)e^x} $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to integrate the folllowing:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+x)e^x} \, dx $$

The major problem that I am facing is eliminating the exponential, I am unable to convert it into something else by substitution means.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a nice closed form solution to this in terms of elementary functions. Wolfram Alpha gives this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E%28-x%29%2F%281%2Bx%29+from+x%3D0..1 which is just a redefinition of your integral..

Answer (score 0):

The antiderivative is not elementary.  Maple gives the integral as
$$ {\it Ei} \left( 1,1 \right) {\rm e}-{\it Ei} \left( 1,2 \right) {\rm e
}
$$
where $Ei$ is the Exponential Integral function.  It can also be expressed in terms of the incomplete Gamma function:
$$ \Gamma(0,1) e - \Gamma(0,2) e$$
or the Logarithmic Integral function:
$$ {\it Li}(1/e^2) e - {\it Li}(1/e) e $$
I doubt that you can get anything more "closed-form" than that.

Answer (score 0):

It's a hard one to solve, but we know the answer! So can work to an exact answer:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+x)e^x} \, dx =\left[e\left(Ei(-x-1)\right)\right]^{1}_{0}=$$

$$\left(e\left(Ei(-1-1)\right)\right)-\left(e\left(Ei(-0-1)\right)\right)=$$

$$e\left(Ei(-2)-Ei(-1)\right)=e\left(\ln(2)+\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{(-2)^k-(-1)^k}{kk!}\right)=$$

$$-e(-\Gamma(0,1)-\ln(1))+e\left(-\Gamma(0,2)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\ln(-2)-\ln\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)-\ln(2)\right)$$